# SoftArtisans 'Border.Part.Outline' work as SoftArtisans 'Border.Part.All'

Tags: excel

SoftArtisans library - Excel 97

SoftArtisans 'Border.Part.Outline' work as SoftArtisans 'Border.Part.All'.

Description: Excel 2016 '/Home/Outside Borders' option is equivalent of SoftArtisans 'Border.Part.Outline'
 The problem is simple. This never work as expected.

If we get some cell range for example from 1 to 10 -> rows[1:10] without merge those range cells then set border '**Border.Part.Outline**' option work as '**Border.Part.All**' which is wrong.

Here some pseudo code:

```
var myRange = getMyCustRange(myRows[1:10]);
 Style mystyle  = Workbook.GlobalStyle.CreateStyle();

 // If I want to clear border
 mystyle.Border[Border.Part.All] =  Border.LineStyle.None; // test pass, worked!

 // If I want to set border to all cell part of the current range
 mystyle.Border[Border.Part.All] =  Border.LineStyle.Thin; // test pass, worked!

 // If I want to remove Outside Borders
 mystyle.Border[Border.Part.Outline] =  Border.LineStyle.None; // test pass, worked!

 // If I want to set only Outside Borders into current range with more than one rows and thoose rows are not merged -> Area.MergeCells();
 mystyle.Border[Border.Part.Outline] =  Border.LineStyle.Thin; // test FAILED!!!



// Part : TypesafeEnum       
        Border.Part All;
        Border.Part Bottom;
        Border.Part DiagonalBoth;
        Border.Part DiagonalDown;
        Border.Part DiagonalUp;
        Border.Part Left;
        Border.Part Outline;
        Border.Part Right;
        Border.Part Top;
```

Comment: Can somebody with tag access to associate a new tag #SoftArtisans for this question. Thanks. I do not have access to add tag like #SoftArtisans  into this question.